# Making my own debugger

Tags: java, debugging, bytecode

I project to build my own bytecodes debugger to view:

> - the currents "objects" in the operands stack;
> - to have a visual representation of frames;
> - to have a list of declared objects in the Java heap (of the running program);
> - to have a list of constant pools, etc

The problem is I want to set up in place a breakpoint options to my program and to see the application in real.

I looked on the internet the way to do a debugger, and I found JDPA wich could probably help me doing my project.

But, I am not sure its the good thing, cause I don't want a Java debugger, I really need a Bytecode debugger.

How can I insert bytecodes break points in a project ? I see on the internet that "0xca is reserved as a breakpoint instruction for debuggers and is not used by the language". Is it the good way ?

Answer (score 2):

Option#1 : 
Using JPDA you can use `com.sun.jdi.request.EventRequestManager.createBreakpointRequest()` method you can add a breakpoint to any `Location`.  Per the Java documentation on the `Location` class it is

> *A point within the executing code of the target VM.*

It may be a bytecode location or the source line location.

Option#2: If you can find the method in which the bytecode lies you can place an artificial breakpoint in your JPDA-based debugger because you can tell the offset of the bytecode from the start of the function.